# "undefined control sequence" error message in tex file

Tags: errors

When I run my .tex, this message appears. But my .pdf file is fine.
What can i do?

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./final version.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \documentclass
                  [12pt]{amsart}
?
```

Comment: You must compile with pdflatex,  not with pdftex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.